# How do I diagnose light dimmers that have become erratic after installation?

Tags: lighting, electrical-panel, dimmer-switch

I used to have light dimmers in my house that worked just fine; but after an electrical panel upgrade they became erratic and/or noisy.  All the dimmers are powering LEDs which claim to be dimmable and the dimmers claim to be LED-friendly.  And this used to be true, before the panel upgrade.

The first one we noticed, and which we tried to show the electrician who did the panel work, would become flickery when the vacuum cleaner or the toaster oven were running (both on different circuits) but it would only do it sometimes and of course it never when he was looking; so he shrugged and said to just keep an eye on it.  Eventually we gave up and removed the dimmer.

Another light started buzzing after the panel was upgraded, and we assumed the light was faulty and replaced it but the new one also buzzed, and I only realised the other day when I decided I didn't want a dimmer there that removing the dimmer fixed the light.

Other lights on dimmers struggle to start when they used to have no trouble starting at all.

I can't think what could happen at the panel that could make this sort of thing happen... or what other environmental factors might happen at around the same time

Comment: Dimming LEDs is a black art.  Even the dimmer manufacturers want to list very particular LEDs their dimmer is rated to work with.  Of course consumers want none of that, they want the cheapest that China can produce.  So it ends up being a can of worms.   On the panel, correllation is not causality, but given the spectacular nature of panel failures, I would be cautious, and treat the failing LEDs like a "canary in the coal mine" portent, and search for a problem with the new panel...

Comment: I agree with the Canary concern since they worked in the past.+